Google Wallet JWT Payload in PHP
I'm working with the Google Wallet API and would like to integrate the function createJwtExistingObjects(string $issuerId) from https://github.com/google-wallet/rest-samples/blob/main/php/demo_eventticket.php into my solution.
To replicate the JWT object, I transformed this:
{
  "id": "ISSUER_ID.CLASS_ID",
  "classTemplateInfo": {
    "cardTemplateOverride": {
      "cardRowTemplateInfos": [
        {
          "twoItems": {
            "startItem": {
              "firstValue": {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "fieldPath": "object.ticketHolderName",
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
            "endItem": {
              "firstValue": {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "fieldPath": "object.ticketHolderName",
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          "twoItems": {
            "startItem": {
              "firstValue": {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "fieldPath": "class.dateTime.start",
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
            "endItem": {
              "firstValue": {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "fieldPath": "object.ticketNumber",
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}

into the following PHP code:
        'classTemplateInfo' => new ClassTemplateInfo([
            'cardTemplateOverride' => new CardTemplateOverride([
                'cardRowTemplateInfos' => array(new CardRowTemplateInfo([ 
                    'twoItems' => new CardRowTwoItems([
                        'startItem' => new TemplateItem([
                            'firstValue' => new FieldSelector([
                                'fields' => [new FieldReference(
                                    ['fieldPath' => 'object.ticketHolderName']
                                )]
                            ])
                        ]), 
                        'endItem' => new TemplateItem([
                            'firstValue' => new FieldSelector([
                                'fields' => [new FieldReference(
                                    ['fieldPath' => 'object.ticketHolderName']
                                )]
                            ])
                        ]) 
                    ]),
                    'twoItems' => new CardRowTwoItems([
                        'startItem' => new TemplateItem([
                            'firstValue' => new FieldSelector([
                                'fields' => [new FieldReference(
                                    ['fieldPath' => 'class.dateTime.start']
                                )]
                            ])
                        ]), 
                        'endItem' => new TemplateItem([
                            'firstValue' => new FieldSelector([
                                'fields' => [new FieldReference(
                                    ['fieldPath' => 'object.ticketNumber']
                                )]
                            ])
                        ]) 
                    ])
                ]))
            ])
        ]) 

I do not get any PHP or API errors, however only the last row with its two items dateTime.start and ticketNumber are being displayed.
What could be the reason?
